# How to create a Button that changes visuals when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I want to create a Submit button that when clicked once will change it's design from "Submit" to an "I agree to the TOS" checkbox and only once that is checked the actual action/function will initiate.

Does anybody have an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

html:

```
<form>
  <div id="TOC">
      <label for="TOC_check">I agree to TOC</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOC_check"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

css:

```
#TOC { display: none; }
```

js:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    if (!$('#TOC_check').is(':checked')) {
      $('#TOC').show();
      $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('#TOC_check').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('input[type="submit"]').show();
    } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxc9omLv/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are the only siblings you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` like this:

```
 $('myclass').click(function(){//give them the same class name
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).siblings().show();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Html example:

```
<form name="" action="" id="the_form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="some value" style="display: none;" class="check"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_button"/>
</form>
```

Script example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit_button").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(".check").show();
        });
    });
   $(".check").click(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $("#the_form").submit();
       }
   })
})
```

Comment: This will submit the form after first click.

Comment: You are right. I fix my answer by adding event.preventDefault();

Comment: The form must be submitted when checkbox is checked.

Comment: He can call $(form).submit() inside the if()... //Do action

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_button">
<input type="checkbox" value="some value" style="display: none;" class="check">
```

Script example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit_button").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(".check").show();
        });
    });

   $("check").click(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
           //Do action
       }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have HTML like this, wrapped in a `form` tag with `id="form"`

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" /><label>Do you agree?</label> <br />
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

You can use some jQuery to detect the state on submit and modify the button text

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    var isChecked = $("#chk").prop("checked");
    var $btn = $("#btn");

    if (!isChecked) {
        $btn.attr("value", "I agree to the TOS");
        return false;
    }
});
```